# How can i create an AlertDialog after i fetch data from the database?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i create an AlertDialog in flutter after i fetch a data from the database. I'm able to create the AlertDialog but i wanted to change the color of its child container based on the data i fetch from the database. I set a condition for the color parameter but it will not change the container color because the condition is delayed.

Is there anyway i could create delay the creation of the AlertDialog or its Childrens? The below widget is with in the AlerdDialog and i wanted to change its colors after i fetched its status from the database.

```
Expanded(
          child: Container(
              height: size.height * 0.05,
              width: size.width * 0.16,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color:  setCompletedTasksColor(selectedSimName, index) == true ? Colors.green : kSelectedMenuColorLavender,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  )
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(getQtgMonths(index),textAlign : TextAlign.center))),
        ),
```

below is the function to fetch the data from the database

```
Future setCompletedTasksColor(String selectedTask, int index) async {
var response = await fetchSelectedTasks(selectedTask, getQuarter(index));
if(response.runtimeType != String){
  var taskStatus = response['taskCompleted'];
  print(taskStatus);
  if(taskStatus == 'true'){
    return true;
  }else{
   return ;
  }
}else {
  return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply call this function when you get response

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Like this

```
Future setCompletedTasksColor(String selectedTask, int index) async {
var response = await fetchSelectedTasks(selectedTask, getQuarter(index));
if(response.runtimeType != String){
  var taskStatus = response['taskCompleted'];
  print(taskStatus);
  if(taskStatus == 'true'){
    _showMyDialog();//This wil open an alert when response of your request will be true
    return true;
  }else{
   return ;
  }
}else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the above code is that the alert will only run when the task completed condition is met. I want to change the color of the gridview children which are with in the alertDialog body. I wanted i change the background to green for completed tasks and to white for not completed tasks after fetching the status on the database